# How can I pass a pointer from C# to an unmanaged DLL?

Tags: c#, pointers, unmanaged, dllimport, unsafe

I have an unmanaged DLL with a function that takes a pointer as an argument. How do I pass a pointer from C# without being 'unsafe'?

Here's some example code:

```
[DllImport(@"Bird.dll")]
private static extern bool foo(ushort *comport);
```

The corresponding entry in the header:

```
BOOL DLLEXPORT foo(WORD *pwComport);
```

When I try and simply dereference it (`&comport`), I get an error saying: "*Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context.*"

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `ref`:

```
[DllImport(@"Bird.dll")]
private static extern bool foo(ref ushort comport);
```

Call it like so:

```
ushort comport;
foo(ref comport);
```

For interop like this, I'd prefer to use `UInt16` rather than `ushort` as the equivalent to `WORD`.